# Android intent to share text/plain data to Google Drive

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

I've created a simple notepad app which implements the ACTION_SEND share intent to share notes.

My data has the mime type of "text/plain" and Google Drive (formerly Google Docs) is offered as a choice on my device, when I select Google Drive I get the error "This item cannot be uploaded as Google Document" via a Toast message.

I create my share intent like this:

```
Intent share_intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

share_intent.setType("text/plain");
share_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, name);
share_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

startActivity(share_intent);
```

Apps like Mail, Messaging, Twitter and Wordpress all seem to handle the intent well and share at least the EXTRA_TEXT content.

I wonder if there's a way that would allow Google Drive to successfully upload the note, or at least handle the intent better?

I'm new to Android so please forgive my stupidity if this turns out to be a stupid question.
I'm developing against a minimum SDK version 15, if that helps at all.

Here's a screen-grab of the error message:
[image: Screen shot showing error message]

In LogCat I spotted the error message again:

```
05-13 23:31:46.906: E/UploadSharedItemActivity(14594): This item cannot be uploaded as Google Document.
```

There's also a warning which occurs before the error message:

```
05-13 23:31:46.250: W/ND(14594): Could not load Finalizer in its own class loader. Loading Finalizer in the current class loader instead. As a result, you will not be able to garbage collect this class loader. To support reclaiming this class loader, either resolve the underlying issue, or move Google Collections to your system class path.
05-13 23:31:46.250: W/ND(14594): java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/google/inject/internal/Finalizer.class
05-13 23:31:46.250: W/ND(14594):    at NE.a(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:269)
05-13 23:31:46.250: W/ND(14594):    at NE.a(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:253)
```

I don't know if that could be related or not.

I can dump the whole LogCat in here if it will help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Google Drive app. Your code seems fine, and if other apps are handling it without issue, it's unlikely to be a problem on your end. That being said, you could always experiment with other formats (e.g., wrap the thing in some tags and call it `text/html`) and see what happens.

Comment: I think you're right; I just tried sharing some text from the browser app and a few others and I get the same error from there as well. I should have checked this before asking really. 

I will try and wrap my text in tags and share as text/html too, in case this bypasses the problem and report back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot share text to google document, but you can share a file (text file or other)
So, just save your text into a file inside your application and share that file with the Intent :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + your_file_path));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Comment: That's a good solution; it works a treat.

I've added the additional EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT values to the intent as well so that other apps like messaging answer the intent as well. The only problem is that the e-mail client includes the file as an attachment as well as filling the e-mail content with the EXTRA_TEXT and the subject line from the EXTRA_SUBJECT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like this is a bug in Google Drive. I should have checked more thoroughly in other apps before asking here.

I've reported it through the 'Send Feedback' feature of the app. Hopefully someone in the Google software factory will fix it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
   val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    sendIntent.type = "application/pdf"
    sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://$filePath"))
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Whatever you want..."))
```

Comment: You need to add runtime permission, also change type to according to your need. Peace ✌️